# How to set the version of a Node Webkit in gulp file?

Tags: gulp, nw.js

How can I set the version of Node Webkit in gulp file?

I have this code:

```
var nw = new NodeWebkitBuilder({
        version: '0.12.2',
           files: ['./package.json', './app/**/*'].concat(modules),
        platforms: platforms,
        macIcns: './app/assets/icons/play-icon.icns',
        winIco: './app/assets/icons/play-icon.ico'
    })
```

When I run the comman gulp run  it installs the version 0.13.0 bete and I want it the version 0.12.2.

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reference - https://github.com/mllrsohn/node-webkit-builder/blob/master/example/Gulpfile.js

```
   var nw = new NwBuilder({ 
     version: '0.12.2',
     files: ['./package.json', './app/**/*'].concat(modules),
     platforms: platforms,
     macIcns: './app/assets/icons/play-icon.icns',
     winIco: './app/assets/icons/play-icon.ico'
   });
```